# Python Assistant - Responses to variety of sentences.

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me with a small problem. I am looking to start a project to speedup my normal time consuming processes on my computer. Within the code of my 'assistant' I would have all the functions hard coded but I wanted the flexibility of not having to type an exact sentence e.g. 'open sublime text' instead I would like to be able to talk freely and be able to say something along the lines of 'Please open sublime' or 'Can you please open sublime text'. I know that I could do something along the lines of:

`if 'sublime' in text_input:
    sublime()`

The only problem is I have to hard code each one and if any other application have a similar word in the sentence it will perform the first if statement that is met with (if I say google sublime and the if statement for sublime text application is above the google if statement then it will open the application instead of googling it). Is there no simpler way to do this? Something more advanced or easier? Appreciate any help, new to stackoverflow and I am grateful if you could take your time to assist me with my problem.

Comment: so this is not Python related, nor programming problem specifically. I suggest to read some papers and tutorials to grasp the logic, and get some ideas, this is a chatbot field of study.

Comment: @Curcuma_ This does relate to python... It's to be created in python. Not sure where else I could have posted this. I am clearly creating it in python therefore this is the right tag to post it under. Also the problem is I am not sure how to code it in the manner I want. I am asking for assistance with that.

Comment: nevertheless, it is not Python related at all

Comment: @Curcuma_ Not here to argue. I am new to the forum and am posting it where I think most appropriate. I am sorry if it is in the wrong place. Nevertheless it is coded in python and therefore I beg to differ. It is created in PYTHON but you still say it is not PYTHON related?